# While adding a user to the share point group it is displaying the error message?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

[image]

I can select the user,but when i am trying to add them it is gettig converted to some html code !!!

Comment: did u tried to add them by searching.

Comment: Hi Tahmidul,ya i tried to add them by searching

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using? because this could be a browser issue,
if you're using IE, try adding site in trusted site in browser or try another browser like Chrome.

Comment: hi saeed, i am using IE11,thankyou i will try by adding the site to trusted sites.